C# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Unknown error (0xc100000d)'
I attempted implementing an RSA encryption function in C# using .NET v8. The encryption test ran smoothly, but an unexpected exception occurred during the decryption test.
Error detail:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
  HResult=0xC100000D
  Message=Unknown error (0xc100000d)
  Source=System.Security.Cryptography
  StackTrace:
   at Interop.BCrypt.BCryptEncryptRsa(SafeBCryptKeyHandle key, ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Void* pPaddingInfo, BCryptEncryptFlags dwFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt.TryEncrypt(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Encrypt(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt.Encrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
   at FileCryptography.FileEncryptionUtility.Encrypt(Byte[] data, String pemKey) in Class1.cs:line 51
   at FileCryptography.FileEncryptionUtility.EncryptFile(String filePath, String pemKey) in Class1.cs:line 25
   at FileCryptography.FileEncryptionUtility.File_encryption(Boolean Is_encrypt, String File_path, String PEMkey) in Class1.cs:line 14
   at Cry.Form.File_crypt(Boolean Is_encrypt, String File_path) in Form1.cs:line 114
   at Cry.Form.Form_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 203
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean ignoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(HWND hWnd, MessageId msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)


Here is my code:
Class1.cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace FileCryptography
{
    public class FileEncryptionUtility
    {
        public static void File_encryption(bool Is_encrypt, string File_path, string PEMkey)
        {
            if (Is_encrypt)
            {
                EncryptFile(File_path, PEMkey);
            }
            else
            {
                DecryptFile(File_path, PEMkey);
            }
        }

        private static void EncryptFile(string filePath, string pemKey)
        {
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            byte[] encryptedData = Encrypt(data, pemKey);
            File.Delete(filePath);
            string p1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
            string p2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            string p3 = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            string p4 = ".rwnenc";
            string p = $"{p1}{p2}{p3}{p4}";
            File.WriteAllBytes(p, encryptedData);
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        private static void DecryptFile(string filePath, string pemKey)
        {
            byte[] encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            byte[] decryptedData = Decrypt(encryptedData, pemKey);
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
            string filenameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            filenameWithoutExtension = filenameWithoutExtension.Replace(".rwnenc", "");
            string newFilePath = Path.Combine(directory, filenameWithoutExtension);
            File.WriteAllBytes(newFilePath, decryptedData);
        }

        private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, string pemKey)
        {
            using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
            {
                rsa.ImportFromPem(pemKey.ToCharArray());
                return rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, string pemKey)
        {
            using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
            {
                rsa.ImportFromPem(pemKey.ToCharArray());
                return rsa.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
            }
        }
    }
}


I am expecting the program to run smoothly without encountering the error 0xC100000D that indicates Unknown Error

If you're using a public key for encryption, the decryption must be done using the corresponding private key.
Ensure the key parsing is correct. If the PEM key contains line breaks or formatting issues, it could cause the import to fail.
